# delete parent and itself in jquery

Tags: jquery

JQuery:

```
$('#imgDelete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('td').remove();
});
```

All `<td>` are generate pro-grammatically and bind.`imgDelete` is also bind inside for each `<td>`.But above code shouldn't able to remove parent. Dynamically generate columns are unable to delete or i m missing something. Thanks.

Comment: you want to remove td only or whole row in case of row you should try $(this).parent('tr') or $(this).closest('tr') then call remove method

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID in your page. Use a class instead.

Comment: do you mean, this code is doing nothing or works for TDs which loads with DOM ?

Comment: If you're using `live` with an ID selector, you're probably doing it wrong. Where is the relevant markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#imgDelete').live('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('td').remove();
});
```

Look for the difference between `.parent()` and `.parents()`
(I'm supposing that `imgDelete` isn't a direct child of `td`) (Also, you should use class instead of id, as has been said)

Comment: `closest()` would be more appropriate (because it's more efficient), but I couldn't really make enough sense of the question to know whether this is the answer or not.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, `.on` is preferred to `.live`: `$(document).on('click','#imgDelete', function() {...});`

Comment: @eZakto Thanks a lot its work.I m confuse about `parent` and `parents`.@Andy closest() is also another available option.Thanks a lot.